# Jupyter Notebook - incredibly slow code execution after the PC update

Tags: macos, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter

I have just updated my MacBook Air 2014 with 4gb ram to a MacBook pro that is vastly more powerful, with 4* the ram & processing speed and installed the latest version of Anaconda, yet it is painfully slow.

Even the simplest oneliners of code take some 30 seconds to run, and even simple things crash the notebook!

It is almost unusable. I have checked and re-updated Anaconda and all the packages. I am running the latest OS on both laptops (and the MacBook air is faster!).

I have also tried it on both Chrome and Safari - same issue.

Any ideas what this could be?

Answer (score 0):

The OS on your MacBook Pro may be corrupted, try completely reformatting / resetting it to factory defaults.

Comment: This seems to have sorted it thank you! What a pain though, I'd only just finished installing all my software